# lambda as part of a static variable in a template function

Tags: c++, c++17, static-variables, function-templates, generic-lambda

Let's say we define a simple struct `S` containing 2 members (1 int and 1 functor) in a header file. And we create a such struct as a static const variable in a template function `foo` and return the const reference of this struct. Is it legal in c++17? I try to call `foo<int>` in 2 translation units and it works with clang/gcc but fails with Visual Studio. With Visual Studio the second caller returns a wrong `m_n`(0 instead of 5).

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename Func>
struct S {
    int m_n;
    Func m_func;
    S(int n, Func func): m_n(n), m_func(func) {}
};

template<typename T>
auto const& foo() noexcept {
    static auto const s=S(5, [](auto const&) noexcept { std::cout<<"lambda"<<std::endl; });
    return s;
}
```

Comment: Seems fine for me. Small variation (with `constexpr`) succeeds too [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/dUrybS)

Comment: Will it cause linkage problems if used in multiple translation unit? Or maybe Visual Studio has a bug here.

Comment: `template` are `inline` *"by default"*, so ODR should be OK. I bet for msvc bug.

Comment: Which version of VS you are using?

Comment: VS 2017(15.8.0)/VS 2019(16.4.5) both show the same result.